# Boostrap CDN stops modals from showing up

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

So my stylesheets are the following:

```
script(src="/js/application.js")
script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js")
script(src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.min.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/style.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/header.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js")
```

Now I used the standard modal example from w3 school for boostrap: https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

And if I click on the button to show the modal my HTML page loses focus but nothing appears on the page (Making me think it generally worked but could just not display my modal).

If I remove `link(rel="stylesheet",href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")` 
then the modal works just fine but obviously all my other css is gone.

Is anybody aware of this problem and might even have a fix?

Comment: Make sure your personal stylesheets and js files are linked after bootstrap ones. Otherwise bootstrap will override it.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle?

Comment: Why are you linking to Bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js more than once? You only need one link statement to get the CSS and one script statement to get the javascript.  You should have 2 lines of code for the bootstrap files.  Also, like @cb64 said, your personal stylesheets and javascript files should come after any ones from outside vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 versions of Bootstrap. If you are wanting all the CSS from version 4, try using that specific code. Here is the link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: I have applied the suggested changes and my I only have one version of bootstrap now. The Problem still remains, if i run my application using 4.3.0 then I cannot open the modal, if I remove it and instead use version 3.3.4 I can open it. Now that doesn't help me because from what it looks like I have to keep both versions to keep my style correctly.

Comment: It appears you found your solution. I would recommend you include more code for future reference. This would get your problem answered in seconds. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issue, I was using incompatible js and css versions of bootstrap.